# Getting the App Store and Google Play country on React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-play, app-store

Is there a reliable way of getting the country code of the App/Play Store the user has downloaded the app from?

I've looked around a bit for this, and so far it seems that this is not possible and of the methods that do exist, nothing is reliable. For example, with the `Telephony` API, I can get the country code of the SIM card, but what if the user has a Polish SIM, but lives in the Czech Republic? Any way to get reliable data on this?

Any help is appreciated.